# How to nicely measure runs of same-data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to give a function an arbitrary  dataframe,  dateindex, and column and ask it to return how many continuous preceding rows (including itself) had the same value.  I've been able to keep most of my pandas code vectorized. Struggling to think how I can do this cleanly though.

Below is a small toy dataset and examples of what outputs I'd want from the function.

```
            bar     foo
2016-06-01  False   True
2016-06-02  True    False
2016-06-03  True    True
2016-06-06  True    False
2016-06-07  False   False
2016-06-08  True    False
2016-06-09  True    False
2016-06-10  False   True
2016-06-13  False   True
2016-06-14  True    True


import pandas as pd

rng = pd.bdate_range('6/1/2016', periods=10)
cola = [True, False, True, False, False, False,False, True, True, True]
colb = [False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, True]

d = {'foo':pd.Series(cola, index =rng), 'bar':pd.Series(colb, index=rng)}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)    

"""
consec('foo','2016-06-09') => 4  # it's the fourth  continuous 'False' in a row
consec('foo', '2016-06-08') => 3  # It's the third continuous'False' in a row
consec('bar', '2016-06-02') => 1  # It's the first continuou true in a row
consec('foo', '2016-06-14') => 3  # It's the third continuous True
"""
```

==================

I ended up using the itertools-answer below, with a small change, because it got me exactly what I wanted (slightly more involved than my original question spec). Thanks for the many suggestions.

```
rng = pd.bdate_range('6/1/2016', periods=100)
cola = [True, False, True, False, False, False,False, True, True, True]*10
colb = [False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, True]*10

d = {'foo':pd.Series(cola, index =rng), 'bar':pd.Series(colb, index=rng)}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)    

def make_new_col_of_consec(df,col_list):
    for col_name in col_list:
        lst = []
        for state, repeat_values in itertools.groupby(df1[col_name]):
            if state == True:
                lst.extend([i+1 for i,v in enumerate(repeat_values)])
            elif state == False:
                lst.extend([0 for i,v in enumerate(repeat_values)])
        df1[col_name + "_consec"] = lst
    return df


print make_new_col_of_consec(df1,["bar","foo"])
```

The output as follows:

```
              bar    foo  bar_consec  foo_consec
2016-06-01  False   True           0           1
2016-06-02   True  False           1           0
2016-06-03   True   True           2           1
2016-06-06   True  False           3           0
2016-06-07  False  False           0           0
2016-06-08   True  False           1           0
2016-06-09   True  False           2           0
2016-06-10  False   True           0           1
2016-06-13  False   True           0           2
2016-06-14   True   True           1           3
2016-06-15  False   True           0           4
2016-06-16   True  False           1           0
2016-06-17   True   True           2           1
2016-06-20   True  False           3           0
2016-06-21  False  False           0           0
2016-06-22   True  False           1           0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative method which creates a new column with the relevant consecutive count for each row. I tested this when the dataframe has 10000 rows and it took 24 ms. It uses `groupby` from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html). It takes advantage of the fact that a break is created whenever the key value, in this case `foo` and `bar` changes so we can just use the index from there.

```
rng = pd.bdate_range('6/1/2016', periods=10000)
cola = [True, False, True, False, False, False,False, True, True, True]*1000
colb = [False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, True]*1000

d = {'foo':pd.Series(cola, index =rng), 'bar':pd.Series(colb, index=rng)}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)    

def make_new_col_of_consec(df,col_list):
    for col_name in col_list:
        lst = []
        for state, repeat_values in itertools.groupby(df1[col_name]):
            lst.extend([i+1 for i,v in enumerate(repeat_values)])
        df1[col_name + "_consec"] = lst
    return df


print make_new_col_of_consec(df1,["bar","foo"])
```

Output:

```
              bar    foo  bar_consec  foo_consec
2016-06-01  False   True           1           1
2016-06-02   True  False           1           1
2016-06-03   True   True           2           1
2016-06-06   True  False           3           1
2016-06-07  False  False           1           2
2016-06-08   True  False           1           3
...
[10000 rows x 4 columns]
10 loops, best of 3: 24.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: I used this because it was so close to the endpoint I wanted.  I added a conditional to fill with 0's instead of runs of 1..n when the base state was `False`.   I'll put my code in an edit of my original question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [135]: %paste
def consec(df, col, d):
    return (df[:d].groupby((df[col] != df[col].shift())
                           .cumsum())[col]
                  .transform('size').tail(1)[0])
## -- End pasted text --

In [137]: consec(df, 'foo', '2016-06-09')
Out[137]: 4

In [138]: consec(df, 'foo', '2016-06-08')
Out[138]: 3

In [139]: consec(df, 'bar', '2016-06-02')
Out[139]: 1

In [140]: consec(df, 'bar', '2016-06-14')
Out[140]: 1
```

Explanation:

```
In [141]: (df.foo != df.foo.shift()).cumsum()
Out[141]:
2016-06-01    1
2016-06-02    2
2016-06-03    3
2016-06-06    4
2016-06-07    4
2016-06-08    4
2016-06-09    4
2016-06-10    5
2016-06-13    5
2016-06-14    5
Freq: B, Name: foo, dtype: int32

In [142]: df.groupby((df.foo != df.foo.shift()).cumsum()).foo.transform('size')
Out[142]:
2016-06-01    1
2016-06-02    1
2016-06-03    1
2016-06-06    4
2016-06-07    4
2016-06-08    4
2016-06-09    4
2016-06-10    3
2016-06-13    3
2016-06-14    3
Freq: B, dtype: int64

In [143]: df.groupby((df.foo != df.foo.shift()).cumsum()).foo.transform('size').tail(1)
Out[143]:
2016-06-14    3
Freq: B, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#reorder index in df
df = df[::-1]

def consec(col, date):
    #select df by date
    df1 = df.ix[date:,:]
    #get first group == 1
    colconsec = (df1[col] != df1[col].shift()).cumsum() == 1
    return 'Value is ' + str(df1.ix[0,col]) + ', Len is: '+ str(len(df1[colconsec]))

print (consec('foo', '2016-06-09'))
print (consec('foo', '2016-06-08')) 
print (consec('bar', '2016-06-02'))   
print (consec('foo', '2016-06-14'))   
Value is False, Len is: 4
Value is False, Len is: 3
Value is True, Len is: 1
Value is True, Len is: 3
```

Another solution with finding last value of Series `colconsec` by `iat` for creating mask:

```
def consec(col, date):
    df1 = df.ix[:date,:]
    colconsec = (df1[col] != df1[col].shift()).cumsum() 
    mask = colconsec == colconsec.iat[-1]
    return 'Value is ' + str(df1[col].iat[-1]) + ', Len is: '+ str(len(df1[mask]))

print (consec('foo', '2016-06-09'))
print (consec('foo', '2016-06-08')) 
print (consec('bar', '2016-06-02'))   
print (consec('foo', '2016-06-14')) 
Value is False, Len is: 4
Value is False, Len is: 3
Value is True, Len is: 1
Value is True, Len is: 3
```